# How to check if it is zero datetime in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

How to check if it is zero datetime in c#? What I mean zero datetime is: `01.01.0001 00:00:00`

Comment: If you need to be checking against this value, it would probably be better to use a `Nullable<DateTime>`. Try using `DateTime?` as a type which will allow `null` as a value. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You'll want to check against `DateTime.MinValue`

[More info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx)

Answer (score 21):

You should check against `default(DateTime)`

The value of that is the same as `DateTime.MinValue` but formally `default(T)` is better. It is more readable and more in line with `default(int)` , which is `0` and very different from `int.MinValue`.

In a generic class, `default(T)` works for DateTime as it does for all built-in value types.

Answer (score 5):

you can use [DateTime.MinValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx)

> value of this constant is equivalent to 00:00:00.0000000, January 1, 0001.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you want something like this:

```
if (myDateTime == DateTime.MinValue)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```